# C# to swift4 am trying to use gZIP library in swift but not matching with the compression string with C#

Tags: c#, swift, swift3

The following method is used to compress the string in c#  am trying with the swift using GzipSwift library but it is not matching please help :

Here is c# code :

Compress string with input text

```
public static string CompressString(string text)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
        gZipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    var compressedData = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
    memoryStream.Read(compressedData, 0, compressedData.Length);
    var gZipBuffer = new byte[compressedData.Length + 4];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(compressedData, 0, gZipBuffer, 4, compressedData.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gZipBuffer, 0, 4);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(gZipBuffer);
}
```

Here is the swift Code :

```
let compressedData: Data = try! data.gzipped()
```

Comment: You have to use the same encoding to have the same bytes for compression. In c# code you use UTF8 but in swift you use the default encoding

Comment: Thanks but am doing it let input = "AASFFFFF....."
let data = input.data(using: .utf8)! actually the problem with +4 do't know why in c# they are doing it ?

Comment: The c# code write the length of the buffer at the first 4 bytes of gZipBuffer